# Zune Lcd API Source On My PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, api, dll, zune

I'm trying to get the source of this [project](http://zunelcd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) to build and run on my computer (64-bit, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (though I believe my copy of VS is 32-bit, and the Zune software is, of course, 64-bit)). The solution comes with several projects, but I'm only concerned with ZuneLcdApi and ZuneLcdApiDebug. If I try running the debug program, I get XamlParseException. I Didn't even want to bother with that, so I started my own project in the solution. All my program does is ZuneLcdApi.Launch(), but it doesn't work. I get "Could not load file or assembly 'X, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=(some characters)' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." where x is one of the ZuneLcdApi dependencies (UIX, ZuneDbApi, or ZuneShell).

Anyone have any ideas? The project is sort of old so I don't know if I'll be able to reach out to the developer. I'll try, but in the meantime, I'd really like to know how to start using this API, because it's really incredible.

-edit-

I tried a different computer, and now the debug wpf application works fine. But still, my own windows form c# application gives me "Could not load file or assembly 'UIX, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddd0da4d3e678217' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." How come it can't be found in my project but it *can* be found in the debug program? They both get copied to the exact same directory!

Comment: Do you have that DLL?

Comment: Sure do. The reference is added in the ZuneLcdApi project, and copied from the Zune installation folder into the debug folder. I checked the debug folder, and all three dll's are present.

Comment: They're in my own project, too, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was x86 instead of any cpu. I had to go into build>configuration manager to switch the project over. Once I did that, it was smooth sailing.